# Kendo UI waterfall custom data

Tags: kendo-ui, waterfall

I 'd created a waterfall with similar to waterfall chart given in the demo section. I would like to add a Running time at the end of the chart with value starting from 0.

Please find here the dojo https://dojo.telerik.com/EgABaJiR/2

Required output is like in the image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your question. I don't understand what you mean by "I would like to add a net time at the end of the chart with value starting from 0." But based on your image, I'm guessing you want the column upside down and hitting the 0 axis. On that note, you can try these as the last value in your `cashFlowData`:

1. `{ "name": "Running Time", "summary": "total" }`
2. `{ "name": "Running Time", "druation": -12.5 }`
3. `{ "name": "Running Time", "summary": "runningTotal" }`

All 3 will hit the 0 axis.

> Thank you for your quick answer. But my question is to add the running time at the end, i mean after net time. and it has its own value (15hrs according to my demo) and it should start from 0 axis. Moreover, Summary: total and runningtotal will actually sum from previous column(s). I dont want to sum it from the previous columns

Since this is a waterfall chart then you need to make the last column to zero in order for the 15hrs to start at the zero axis. So a trick would be to make the last values of `cashFlowData` as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Net Time",
  "summary": "total"
},
{
  "name": "Running Time",
  "druation": -12.5,
},
{
  "name": "from zero",
  "druation": 15
}
```

With the above, you'll have 15hrs starting from zero. But I'm guessing you don't want -12.5 rendered. So I'd probably implement something in `series.visual` saying if name equals Running Time then do not draw. You get the idea?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But my question is to add the running time at the end, i mean after net time. and it has its own value (15hrs according to my demo) and it should start from 0 axis. Moreover, Summary: total and runningtotal will actually sum from previous column(s). I dont want to sum it from the previous columns

Comment: Please let me know if you have some dojo if you have achieved it

Comment: Yes i dont want -12.5 rendered. Do you have any sample to implement in series.visual? I tried to hide but the label is not hiding. See here in dojo https://dojo.telerik.com/EgABaJiR/5. But visible function is only working for series, but not for label(category label). Any help will be really appreciable, Thanks